# Каким образом работает BitConverter.ToUint16?

Tags: c#, binary, byte

Я имею два байта, которые в двоичном представлении выглядят подобным образом:

Первый байт: `1001010`

Второй байт: `1111010`

```
BitConverter.ToUint16(new byte[2] { 0b1001010, 0b1111010 })
```

Я ожидаю получить `11110101001010`, а получаю `11110100`(←Появился еще один ноль)`1001010`

Почему итоговый результат отличается от того, что ожидается?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132895/discussion-on-question-by-dungeon-master----bitconverter-tou).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы неправильно прочитали результат. 1 байт = 8 бит, а у вас справа почему-то 7.

Вот так надо. Справа 8 бит, а слева достроить нулями до 8, чтобы получилось всего 16.

```
01111010 01001010
```

Еще скажу, что `BitConverter` уже неактуально использовать, так как результат его работы непредсказуем, в смысле он зависит от архитектуры процессора. Вместо него рекомендуется использовать [BinaryPrimitives](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives).

Comment: Минусующим: так как я не могу удалить принятый ответ, хоть скажите, что исправить то нужно. Ведь должна же быть причина недовольства? Минусы вопросу я тоже не до конца понял.

Comment: Важно то, что при написании какого-то кода, чтобы он был совместим как минимум с предыдущими версиями ... То что вы написали, не является тем что можнг использовать везде

Comment: @ori с предыдущими версиями чего? я ни строчки кода здесь не написал.